# Javascript - Change date from one format to Another

Tags: javascript, date, split

I have a string like this `U{11/12/2016}11/12/2016[19:24:42]` and need to transform it to a string like this one `2016-12-11T19:24:42` where the "2016-12-11 is the date outside the `{}`.

Any thoughts how can I do that?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.split('}')[1].replace('[', 'T').replace(']', '').replace(/\//g,'-')
```

That's it !

```js
   const string = 'U{11/12/2016}11/12/2016[19:24:42]';

    console.log(
      string.split('}')[1].replace('[', 'T').replace(']', '').replace(/\//g,'-')
     )
```

Comment: Thanks it's almost there! Just need to change the date type: "11-12-2016" to "2016-12-11"

Comment: ok.. so add in the same instruction `.split('T').map((e, i) => i ? e : e.split('-').reverse().join('-')).join('T')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
s.replace(/.*\}(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\[(.*)\]/, '$3-$2-$1T$4')
```